# Cant connect to my website from the outside

Tags: networking, apache2, webserver, websites

Hi my network map is like this

> ```
> internet--Arris589--wavlink rounter--my PC== apache2
> ```

my problem is when the web packs come in they get the "this webpage is down message" and when I connect to the page its works. I have already tried port forwarding and set up apache.

This is what my config looks like in apache

[image: Config of my webserver]

my `webhub.network.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.webhub.network
    ServerAlias webhub.network
    DocumentRoot /home/chris/Documents/homeserver/
    <Directory /home/chris/Documents/homeserver/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does your PC have a local firewall enabled that is blocking port 80? Easiest way to check is probably using ufw `sudo ufw status`. If UFW is disabled it won't necessarily mean that your firewall is not blocking the port, see [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) on IPtables to know for sure

Comment: ufw is enabled and its has the apache config in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of *webhub.network.conf* file says, who can go to your webiste. Therefore I recommend you to repace it with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

That means you allow every client to connect with your webserver, if they can reach your port 80.

You can only have one `ServerName`. The other one you can use as `ServerAlias`. [Src](https://serverfault.com/questions/294423/multiple-servername-per-vhost)

---

Make sure, there is a link to *webhub.network.conf* in the *sites-enabled* folder (you can add the link automatically with `a2ensite webhub.network.conf`)

Make sure you set the portforwarding up in your router, so that everybody from the outside can connect to your prot 80.

If it does not work, you also may check that apache has the right to read and send the folder. For example add this code before `</VirtualHost>`. [Src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server#23175981)

```
<Directory /home/chris/Documents/homeserver/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: like this? https://imgur.com/a/pmkYpEx

Comment: I'm sory, the image you uploaded is not working.
Please edit your question and append your *webhub.network.conf* file. When you write '```' in front and after your code, it'll format very nice.

Comment: '```' <Directory /home/chris/Documents/homeserver/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.webhub.network
        ServerAlias webhub.network
        DocumentRoot "/home/chris/Documents/homeserver/"

</VirtualHost>'```'

Comment: The Directory part ist right in front of the end of VirtualHost. I edited your question to with my correction in it. pease try it an tell us how it does.

Comment: I think I can now visit your site: http://webhub.network/. Therefor it seems to work.
PS: It seems www.webhub.network is not registerd in your nameserver. Therefore it does not work.

Comment: if the screen is dark then you can see my page.

Comment: It was dark and I was able to go through your phpinfo page. Be careful what you publish!!!! Now I got 403 messages. I think you organize a login? Good choice. Seems that problem is solved. I'd be happy if you can [accept my answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer). I hope you stay on AskUbuntu and keep using GNU/Linux.

Comment: ya need to change some things on there